# Disable function call to debugger in Chrome Developer Console

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, javascript-debugger

I am using Chrome's Developer Console to study the code of a page, but then the page has a javascript that calls the debugger.

```
(function() {
debugger
})
```

And the page paused, then whenever I press the blue arrow to resume script execution another of such function is called, making it impossible to load the page.  Is there a way to switch off the call to debugger in Chrome such that the page can be load without pausing? I turned off "paused on exception" but it doesn't stop the pausing.

Comment: What worked for me is to deactivate breakpoints -> when you are in devtools -> Ctrl + F8 or the button next to "resume script execution"

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Right-click the line number column next to the line that includes the `debugger` statement and select **Never Pause Here**.

Do this for each instance of `debugger`.

[image: never pause here screenshot]

Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way to disable the `debugger` keyword outright, so I understand that this solution is tedious if you have a lot of calls to `debugger`, but it's the best we have at the moment. I mentioned to the DevTools team (I'm the DevTools technical writer) the need to be able to disable the `debugger` keyword outright.

**Update** A DevTools engineer also reminded me that we have the **Force Resume** button. Hold the Resume button then select **Force Resume** and DevTools ignores all subsequent breakpoints.

[image: force resume]
<sub>(source: [google.com](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/imgs/selecting-force-script-execution.png))</sub>

[documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/reference/#force-resume)

If the script is in a separate file, you can also [blackbox that script](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/reference/#blackbox).

Comment: is it possible that my chrome does not have the **Never stop here** option? cause I can't see it where you show it :(

Comment: It seems that it's possible to disable the `debugger` keyword now, I don't know how, but on drive.google.com, I needed to do `debugger` and it didn't work.

Answer (score 8):

You can deactivate breakpoints:
[image: Ctrl + F8]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, tried all options and then realised that issue was because one of the Chrome extensions!

Try to disable extensions one by one.

Comment: OMG bless you! I've been facing this for MONTHS and now I found out that it was an extension, thank you so much.